# Redirect URL if specific parameter doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters

I have this example URL
www.something.com/order?_vacation=**bahamas**
The Value "**Bahamas**" can vary of course based on the location

I would like to redirect this URL
www.something.com/order
If anyone was typing it in the address bar without the parameter **_vacation** and it's value
Let's say - Redirect him to the homepage
www.something.com

Can anyone suggest how to do it using htaccess?
Thanks

**Update** here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)_vacation=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^order/?$ /? [L,NC,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tripwith/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /tripwith/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule as your topmost rule for this purpose:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)_vacation=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^order/?$ /? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava  I tried that but it's not working
maybe it's because the site has https?  Thanks

Comment: Updated in my answer above

Comment: I just checked your web server is `nginx` but `mod_rewrite` rules are mostly Apache specific

Comment: So I have to check with my server support?

Comment: Yes your server support / admins should be able to handle this.